# Need help on creating a excel worksheet which has frozen columns, which should be allowed during both import and export

Tags: angular

On a button click event ,a excel worksheet should be created and which should have frozen columns, different set of colors for each column and should be allowed during both import and export.

Thanks

Tried using kendo grid, XSLX Workbook, need help on generating template and freezing columns.